# BadTokenException: Unable to add window

Tags: java, android

I have an issue where I receive a `BadTokenException` when the screen times out, and then the user returns to my application. I have a button which opens up a `ContextMenu` when clicked.

It works fine normally, but when the user lets the screen time out, and then returns to the application, a `BadTokenException` is thrown.

```
07-01 14:46:42.763: WARN/WindowManager(1105): Attempted to add window with token that is a sub-window: android.os.BinderProxy@44af17c8.  Aborting.
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:459)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:459)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:459)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:459)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:459)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:2444)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at com.??.??.ui.cards.ViewActivity$3.onClick(ViewActivity.java:353)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    07-01 14:46:42.771: WARN/System.err(1725):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRoot$W@44757528 is not valid; is your activity running?
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:505)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.show(MenuDialogHelper.java:86)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ContextMenuBuilder.show(ContextMenuBuilder.java:88)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.showContextMenuForChild(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:459)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:459)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:459)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:459)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:459)
    07-01 14:46:43.005: WARN/System.err(1725):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:459)
```

If I catch the Exception, the button never opens up the contextmenu in this case, but other controls on the page continue to work.

If I minimize the application with the home screen, and then return, the application crashes with the following trace:

```
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:239)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.closeAll(WindowManagerImpl.java:293)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-01 15:10:50.439: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1931):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's how I'm adding the ContextMenu:

```
b.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View view ) {
                if (contextMenuOpen) return;// popup options
                contextMenuOpen = view.showContextMenu();

            }
```

I do not call registerForContextMenu with the button, but rather the main view itself. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are holding on to a reference to a Context (either explicitly, or by creating a Dialog or Toast or some other dependent item) that has been destroyed (typically because you are using the `onCreateDialog` or you passed the Activity to some other process that didn't get destroyed when the Activity was destroyed).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you mind looking at my edit to the original post and make sure it's valid? I recieve a valid reference to the View inside the onClick function.

Comment: That's really not enough to tell what you are doing wrong: would really need to look at more of your code to determine specifics. What you might try is moving the `setOnClickListener` call into the `onResume` callback for the Activity (make sure you are calling the superclass method as well when you override `onResume`) and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: I ended up resolving this for now, through a different route that would probably not apply to anyone else, and did not actually fix the issue, so I won't explain it here. Thanks

Comment: The issue is related to you creating refrence to some Activity Layout objects. For example declaring a public variable `EditText nameField;` and then in `onCreate` calling `EditText nameField= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameField);`. You should destroy refrences in `onPause()` and recreate in `onResume()`. At least that solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I called method showContextMenu() simply in **onResume** I caught the same Exception. I resolved this issue using Handler

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (contextMenuOpened) {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                choosePicBtn.showContextMenu();
            }
        });
    }
}
```