# Android: “BadTokenException: Unable to add window; is your activity running?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I am opening a `progressdialog` with **AsyncTask** in **doInBackground method** the question is loading from database and after question successfully loaded the progress dialog box will be closed

but my problem is some time I am getting following error

```
      android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRoot$W@44757528 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

by doing some googling I have found that there may be [i am holding on to a reference to a Context (either explicitly, or by creating a Dialog or Toast or some other dependent item) that has been destroyed (typically because you are using the onCreateDialog or you passed the Activity to some other process that didn't get destroyed when the Activity was destroyed).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553724/badtokenexception-unable-to-add-window)

So I have put below code that dismiss progressdialog in-case if activity is destroyed before dialog box is dismissed

```
    protected void onDestroy() {
      if (pdForNewQuestion != null)
            pdForNewQuestion.dismiss();
      super.onDestroy();

    }
```

but I still face the issue. I am not destroying any activity but still the error suddenly comes sometimes and sometimes it works properly

the async code is below

```
      // Start new question in every 60 seconds  :)
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        mProgressStatus++;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                            txtCountingNum.setText((timer--) + "\nSec.");
                            if (timer < 0) {
                                questionLoadWithAsyncTask();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            }

        }
    }).start();




       public void questionLoadWithAsyncTask() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pdForNewQuestion = new ProgressDialog(QuizActivity.this);
            pdForNewQuestion.setTitle("Please wait...");
            pdForNewQuestion.setMessage("Question is loading...");
            pdForNewQuestion.setCancelable(false);
            pdForNewQuestion.setIndeterminate(true);
            pdForNewQuestion.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            wordsCursor = dbHelper.getRandomWords();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (pdForNewQuestion != null) {
                pdForNewQuestion.dismiss();
            }
        }

    }.execute();

}
```

Comment: Post your code for async task, I guess you have not dismissed your progress dialog.

Comment: @Kinjal Please post your `asynctask` code

Comment: @Kinjal Do you get error while rotating mobile or normally getting error?

Comment: No not at time of Rotating but error arise automatically while running my activity it may be some time or in different time :(

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the dialog is showing or not if dialog is showing then only dismiss like this..

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (pdForNewQuestion != null) {
        if (pdForNewQuestion.isShowing()) {
            pdForNewQuestion.dismiss();
            pdForNewQuestion = null;
        }
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Kalyan pvs thanks for your suggestion but error still aries :(

Answer (score 0):

you are running infinite loop inside new Thread but not breaking the loop and stopping that Thread. It runs infinitely in the background even when activity goes background. try stopping the Thread once work is finished.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why are you starting your `AsyncTask` inside a `Thread`? As i understand you are trying to start an `AsyncTask` every 60 seconds and populate a new question. There is a much better way to do this using only a `Handler` and `AsyncTask`.

Create a `Handler` and post `Runnable` which runs every seconds and depending on the result start your `AsyncTask` :

```
    int mSeconds = 0;

    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(mSeconds == 60){
                new QuestionLoader().execute();
                mSeconds = 0;
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            mSeconds++;

        }
    }, 1000);
```

and you can create your `AsyncTask` like this :

```
    private class QuestionLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdForNewQuestion = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pdForNewQuestion.setTitle("Please wait...");
        pdForNewQuestion.setMessage("Question is loading...");
        pdForNewQuestion.setCancelable(false);
        pdForNewQuestion.setIndeterminate(true);
        pdForNewQuestion.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
          wordsCursor = dbHelper.getRandomWords();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(pdForNewQuestion != null && pdForNewQuestion.isShowing()){
            pdForNewQuestion.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by your app trying to display a dialog using a previously-finished Activity as a context. Then check that the activity is not closed by some other apps or other triggers before showing the dialog

```
if (!isFinishing()) {
    //showdialog here
    }
```